# How to create a multi layout page using k2

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

I want to create different layout using k2 component. I have three blog page where i want to show every page are different layout. Where "Categories/item/tag" page show 3 layout system.

How to do that ? any idea.

Comment: Have you done any research at all on the matter? Have you tried anything based on that research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You can try this bellow procedure:***

step 1: Copy the k2 components   **(components->com_k2)**

step 2: Paste **(templates->'your templates'-> inner html folder)**

step 3: Open **(templates->'your templates'-> html -> com_k2)** folder and delete all file except templates folder

step 4: Open **(templates->'your templates'-> html -> com_k2->templates)** folder and copy **default** & paste here with **rename** (suppose '**stackoverflow**') this folder wish you want.

```
    Note: if you want more layout then follow this procedure.
```

step 5: Now you can edit your layout according to your desired.

step 6: Now you have to go **Menu manager** & create new menu where you can see **Menu Item Type** and **select** k2-> your choice. Then next options->
"**Select a template**" where you create '**stackoverflow**'

Comment: I have followed the mentioned step 6 but I was not successfull after selecting the template in K2 category option and it is working fine no need to choose the template in menu option. For example: Components -> K2 -> Categories -> yourcategory and in category layout option select the created template from drop down.